# Bar mitzva if born bein hashmashos?

Tags: halacha, age, safek, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

If a baby is born in the evening during bein hashmashos (typically considered the time from sunset until 3 stars, but see https://outorah.org/p/47194/) the bris is on the latter day, or if Saturday, the bris is pushed to Sunday (this was discussed on this site [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75837/33217)).

But what logic do we follow for determining the age of majority for a baby born during bein hashmashos between day A and day B. Are they an adult 12/13 years later on day A or only on day B? Does the law differ for when they are obligated to do things (eg. don tefillin) vs. when they can do things for others (eg. read Torah)?

Comment: They can read Torah even before bar mitzvah

Comment: @Heshy But is that commonly done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Din Online](https://dinonline.org/2012/06/17/born-after-shkiyah-birthday/):

> ... For purposes of the bar mitzvah — for joining in a minyan and so on: 13 full years are required, and we would use the later date rather than the day before (see Shulchan Aruch Ha-Rav 53:13; Mishnah Berurah 55:42)
>
> However, the boy must be stringent and is considered a gadol from the first of the two days, and therefore the celebration of the Bar Mitzvah should be made on the first day, when he enters the yoke of mitzvos (Shevet Ha-Levi Vol. 4, no. 26).